# Printing out prime numbers based on a previous function in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, primes

I have a function called prime_sieve(N) in python, and this function assigns a 0 to a number if it is not a prime number and 1 if it is a prime number - it is called mask. This function works properly. The problem is in the 2nd function below the code for prime_sieve(N) and the code is:

```
import numpy as np

def prime_sieve(N):
   nums = np.arange(2, N + 2, 1)
   mask = 1 + np.zeroes(N, dtype = int)
   for n in nums:
     for i in np.arange(2 * n - 2, N, n):
         mask[i] = 0

   return nums, mask  

numbers, mask = prime_sieve(8)
print(numbers) #prints out the actual numbers starting at 2
print(mask) #prints out the 0s and 1s assigned to the values if they are a prime or not.
```

I have to use the above mentioned function in a function called primes_list(N) to print out only the prime numbers from the list. The code for primes_list(N) is:

```
def primes_list(N):
  
  for i in range (0, N, 1):

    if mask[i] == 1:
       return prime_sieve(numbers[i])

print(primes_list(8))
```

The output I receive from the prime_sieve(N) function is:

> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>
> [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

The output I receive from the primes_list(N) function is:

> Expected output: [2, 3, 5, 7]
>
> My output: (array([2, 3]), array([1, 1]))

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: My version of numpy has no zeroes, it has zeros though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `primes_list` doesn't make sense:

```
def primes_list(N):
  for i in range (0, N, 1):
    if mask[i] == 1:
       return prime_sieve(numbers[i])
```

`mask` is not defined, and even if you're using the mask from earlier, it will be true at `2`, which will then call `prime_sieve(numbers[2])` where `numbers` is also undefined. If we further accept the global `numbers`, that gives us `prime_sieve[3]`, regardless of what `N` they put in (where `N >= 3`). The result of `prime_sieve[3]` is a tuple: `([2, 3], [1, 1])`.

Try:

```
def primes_list(N):
  nums, mask = prime_sieve(N)
  return [nums[i] for i in range(len(nums)) if mask[i]]
```

This takes the results of `prime_sieve` and only returns the numbers which are prime: (where `mask[i] == True`)

Result: `[2, 3, 5, 7]`

Answer (score -2):

return immediately exits the function and gives you whatever the value is at that point.

Try for example,

```
def f():
    for i in (1, 2, 3):
        return i
print(f())
```

This just prints 1.

You need to either return a tuple of the stuff you want, e.g.

```
def f():
    return (1, 2, 3)

print(f())
```

or use the yield statement, e.g.

```
def f():
    for i in (1, 2, 3):
        yield i

for thing in f():
    print(thing)
```